# Gstreamer record buffer to binary file

Tags: c++, file, gstreamer, kurento, descriptor

I have some question about Gstreamer. I want to use Gstreamer to write buffer to file descriptor when receiving audio/video. I've tried to look up in [GstBuffer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstBuffer.html) function but It's cannot decoding binary file to audio. (I've been using Audacity to convert this raw binary file to media.) Please suggest me to implement that.

PS. Sorry for my bad in English, I'll try to more practices. :)

Comment: Please explain more what you actually want to do. Do you need raw, decoded audio and video data?  What pipeline do you use?

Comment: @micha137 we want to get a raw audio from a stream, so nowadays we try to use **GstMapInfo** to grabbing raw audio from GStreamer but when I have been written raw audio to file it's cannot play via an application.